# Changing folder ownership from the php

Tags: php, linux, shell, unix

I am making a folder from the browser so its ownership becomes the www-data as my apache user is www-data.

What I want to do is use chown command and change the permission of the folder to root I don't want to change the apache user.

I have got 1 solution and it is not working.

exexuting below command from the php file nad pass.txt contains my root password.

```
sudo -u root -S {{ chown root:root abcd }} < pass.txt
```

I am not able to chage the ownership is there any thing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: This is use for php exec("chown -R "root":"root" abcd);

Comment: Why are you using Bash brace expansion in your command? Also, there are many reasons why this might be failing. Have you checked your error logs for your PHP process?  We need more to help you with this.

Comment: @KamleshSolanki I want to executing command with sudo.

I have done what you have said as well.

Comment: @GregT. In error log I am getting password for www-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow `www-data` to execute `/bin/chown` without password-entry via `visudo`:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chown
```

then excute a simple sudo-comand from php: `system("/usr/bin/sudo /bin/chown root:root abcde");`

Comment: didn't get this

Comment: Then read the documentation for `sudo`, `visudo` and the `sudoers` file...

Comment: I got it.  Can I do it from the php file or through script ??

Comment: But I want to do all things from the script

Comment: Then you can't use sudo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170349/discussion-between-tom-regner-and-sagarvirpara).